# Wpf: как переназначить DataContext во внутреннем UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно создать два UserControl, один находится внутри другого. В каждом есть по DataGrid, которые отображают информацию из разных таблиц базы данных.

Проблема: Я смог всё настроить для внешнего UserControl, но внутренний либо автоматически перехватывает DataContext своего родителя (и отображает неправильные данные в DataGrid), либо (когда я пытаюсь задать DataContext напрямую) не отображает вообще ничего, хотя, судя по коду, получение информации из БД проходит нормально.

Внешний UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AppM.Views.ListViews.UserListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:AppM.ViewModels"
         xmlns:service="clr-namespace:AppM.Base"
         xmlns:commandBehaviors="clr-namespace:AppM.CommandBehaviors"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppM.Views.FormViews"
         xmlns:listViews="clr-namespace:AppM.Views.ListViews"
         service:DialogService.IsRegisteredView="True"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:UsersViewModel}"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <listViews:RoleValueConverter x:Key="roleValueConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" MinWidth="120">Обновить</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="Пользователи" Margin="5">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button>Создать</Button>
                    <Button>Редактировать</Button>
                    <Button>Удалить</Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Label}" Header="Логин" Width="0.75*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="ФИО" Width="2*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DateBirth, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" Header="Дата рождения" Width="0.75*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=USERROLE, Converter={StaticResource roleValueConverter}}" Header="Роль" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <!-- Внутренний UserControl здесь -->
        <Expander Header="Роли" Margin="5">
            <local:UserRoleView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding viewModels:UserRoleViewModel}"/>
            <!-- судя по всему, не работает-->
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Внутренний UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AppM.Views.FormViews.UserRoleView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:AppM.ViewModels"
         xmlns:service="clr-namespace:AppM.Base"
         xmlns:commandBehaviors="clr-namespace:AppM.CommandBehaviors"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppM.Views.FormViews"
         xmlns:listViews="clr-namespace:AppM.Views.ListViews"
         service:DialogService.IsRegisteredView="True"

         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:UserRoleViewModel}"
         >
 <!-- Если добавить DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModels:UserRoleViewModel}}" - не может найти UserRoleViewModel -->
 <!-- Если добавить DataContext="{Binding viewModels:UserRoleViewModel}" - просто ничего не показывает в DataGrid -->

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button>Создать</Button>
            <Button>Редактировать</Button>
            <Button>Удалить</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Label}" Header="Наименование" Width="2*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AccessLevel}" Header="Доступ" Width="3*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Прошу помочь.

Вопрос вдогонку: может быть, будет логичнее вынести DataGridы в отдельные UserControlы, которые оба будут в третьем UserControl?

Answer (score 3):

Вот эта строчка, что по Вашему делает?:

```
<local:UserRoleView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding viewModels:UserRoleViewModel}"/>
```

У Вас где-то есть класс, `UserRoleViewModel`, но сначала надо создать его экземпляр, где у Вас этот экземпляр? Вы смотрите, что пишется в Output окне Visual Studio, когда запускаете программу, там можно увидеть ошибки.

Можно, конечно, создать его прямо в XAML, тогда это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
<local:UserRoleView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<local:UserRoleView.DataContext>
    <viewModels:UserRoleViewModel />
</local:UserRoleView.DataContext>
<local:UserRoleView/>
```

Но если этот объект уже где-то создаётся, то нужно думать, как его сюда передать. Черезе родительский `DataContext`, скорее всего.